# How to get back data from activity to React-native which is called by intent

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module

I want to get data back from a activity which i called from react native module

```
 @ReactMethod
public void callNewActivity(String code, Callback runner){
    Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, novaActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

i want to invoke **runner** callback with a string param which will came "novaActivity"